# PHP How detect randomly generated IP from HTTP Request?

Tags: php, http-headers, httpwebrequest, ip

I have created one web application using PHP. I want know the IP randomly generated or not from proxy or client side application. Our application only allow one click per IP address.
I had checked the user agent by using `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`. I got the user agent currently. but I want know whether the user agent using  any other tool to generate IP address
dynamically. is it possible to check by using the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this piece of code:

```
if (
      $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']
   || $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']
   || $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']
   || $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']
   || $_SERVER['HTTP_VIA']
   || in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'], array(8080,80,6588,8000,3128,553,554))
   || @fsockopen($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 80, $errno, $errstr, 30))
{
    exit('Proxy detected');
}
```

Source: [digitalpoint](http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=58964)

Comment: Where i get the value of variables  $errno and $errstr ?
Is this code help me  to detect IP is dynamically generated or nor?
Some time the client using proxy server and  i want allow only one request per ip(For checking)

Comment: Please see http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php, these variables are passed by reference. This code will detect if the user is using a proxy service. Most of the IPs are dynamically generated - at least the personal ones. Static IPs are mostly used for companies. When you are saying dynamically generated, I am guessing you mean using a proxy service?

Comment: Very useful information.How detect anonymous proxy server by using PHP Code?